# Regex start new match at specific pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Hello im kinda new to regex and have a small, maybe simple question.

I have the given text:

```
17.11.2020 15:32 typical Pat. seems sleeping
Additional test

17.11.2020 15:32 typical Pat. seems sleeping
Additional test

17.11.2020 15:32 typical Pat. seems sleeping
Additional test
```

My current regex `(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2})\s?(.*)`
matches only till sleeping but reates 3 matches correctly.
But i need the `Additional test` text also in the second group.
i tried something like `(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2})\s?([,.:\w\s]*)` but now i have only one huge match because the second group takes everything until the end.

How can i match everything until a new line with a date starts and create a new match from there on?

Comment: Try `(?m)^(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2})[\p{Zs}\t]*(.*)\r?\n(.*)`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%5e%28%5cd%7b2%7d%5c.%5cd%7b2%7d%5c.%5cd%7b4%7d%5cs%5cd%7b2%7d%3a%5cd%7b2%7d%29%5b%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%5d*%28.*%29%5cr%3f%5cn%28.*%29&i=17.11.2020+15%3a32+typical+Pat.+seems+sleeping%0d%0aAdditional+test%0d%0a%0d%0a17.11.2020+15%3a32+typical+Pat.+seems+sleeping%0d%0aAdditional+test%0d%0a%0d%0a17.11.2020+15%3a32+typical+Pat.+seems+sleeping%0d%0aAdditional+test). Or, `(?m)^(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}[\p{Zs}\t]\d{2}:\d{2})[\p{Zs}\t]*(.*)\r?\n(?s)(.*?)(?=\n\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}|\z)`

Comment: You are using `\s` repeatedly in a characters class, which also matches newlines and will match too much. You can just take out the `\s` and match the rest of the line and match a newline. `(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2})\s?(.*\r?\n.*)` https://regex101.com/r/LjvLh0/1

Comment: ^(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2})\s*(.*\r?\n?.*) worked @WiktorStribiżew. i used and changed yours because i didnt understand some things but still worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure there is only one additional line  to be matched you can use

```cs
(?m)^(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2})\s*(.*(?:\n.*)?)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B4%7D%5Cs%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%5Cs*%28.*%28%3F%3A%5Cn.*%29%3F%29&i=17.11.2020%2015%3A32%20typical%20Pat.%20seems%20sleeping%0D%0AAdditional%20test%0D%0A%0D%0A17.11.2020%2015%3A32%20typical%20Pat.%20seems%20sleeping%0D%0AAdditional%20test%0D%0A%0D%0A17.11.2020%2015%3A32%20typical%20Pat.%20seems%20sleeping%0D%0AAdditional%20test). Details:

- `(?m)` - a multiline modifier
- `^` - start of a line
- `(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2})` - Group 1: a datetime string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*(?:\n.*)?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than a newline char as many as possible and then an optional line, a newline followed with any zero or more chars other than a newline char as many as possible.

If there can be any amount of lines, you may consider

```cs
(?m)^(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}[\p{Zs}\t]\d{2}:\d{2})[\p{Zs}\t]*(?s)(.*?)(?=\n\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}|\z)
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B4%7D%5B%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5Ct%5D%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%5B%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5Ct%5D*%28%3Fs%29%28.*%3F%29%28%3F%3D%5Cn%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B4%7D%7C%5Cz%29&i=17.11.2020%2015%3A32%20typical%20Pat.%20seems%20sleeping%0D%0AAdditional%20test%0D%0A%0D%0A17.11.2020%2015%3A32%20typical%20Pat.%20seems%20sleeping%0D%0AAdditional%20test%0D%0A%0D%0A17.11.2020%2015%3A32%20typical%20Pat.%20seems%20sleeping%0D%0AAdditional%20test). Here,

- `(?m)^(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}[\p{Zs}\t]\d{2}:\d{2})` - matches the same as above, just `\s` is replaced with `[\p{Zs}\t]` that only matches horizontal whitespace
- `[\p{Zs}\t]*` - 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?s)` - now, `.` will match any chars including a newline
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\n\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}|\z)` - up to the leftmost occurrence of a newline, followed with a date string, or up to the end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `\s` repeatedly using the `*` quantifier with the character class `[,.:\w\s]*` and `\s` also matches newlines and will match too much.

You can just match the rest of the line using `(.*\r?\n.*)` which would not match a newline, then match a newline and the next line in the same group.

```
^(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2})\s?(.*\r?\n.*)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5cd%7b2%7d.%5cd%7b2%7d.%5cd%7b4%7d%5cs%5cd%7b2%7d%3a%5cd%7b2%7d%29%5cs%3f%28.*%5cr%3f%5cn.*%29&i=17.11.2020+15%3a32+typical+Pat.+seems+sleeping%0d%0aAdditional+test%0d%0a%0d%0a17.11.2020+15%3a32+typical+Pat.+seems+sleeping%0d%0aAdditional+test%0d%0a%0d%0a17.11.2020+15%3a32+typical+Pat.+seems+sleeping%0d%0aAdditional+test&o=m)

If multiple lines can follow, match all following lines that do not start with a date like pattern.

```
^(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})\s*(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}).*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `(` Capture group1
- `\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}` Match a date like pattern
- `)` Close **group 1**
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars (Or match whitespace chars without newlines `[^\S\r\n]*`)
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `.*` Match the whole line
  - `(?:\r?\n(?!\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}).*)*` Optionally repeat matching the whole line if it does not start with a date like pattern
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5cd%7b2%7d%5c.%5cd%7b2%7d%5c.%5cd%7b4%7d%29%5cs*%28.*%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!%5cd%7b2%7d%5c.%5cd%7b2%7d%5c.%5cd%7b4%7d%29.*%29*%29&i=17.11.2020+15%3a32+typical+Pat.+seems+sleeping%0d%0aAdditional+test%0d%0a%0d%0a17.11.2020+15%3a32+typical+Pat.+seems+sleeping%0d%0aAdditional+test%0d%0a%0d%0a17.11.2020+15%3a32+typical+Pat.+seems+sleeping%0d%0aAdditional+test%0d%0aAdditional+test%0d%0aAdditional+test%0d%0aAdditional+test%0d%0a%0d%0a17.11.2020+15%3a32+typical+Pat.+seems+sleeping%0d%0aAdditional+test&o=m)